# Does PHP have the equivilant to Java 'synchronized' , or is this not required?

Tags: php

I am familiar with Java and at the moment I am teaching myself PHP. To prevent race conditions and deadlocks, Java uses the keyword 'synchronized'.

From Oracle docs:

```
public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
}
```

I am using prepared statements within a separate class to access my database. I wish to avoid race conditions, deadlocks etc, but I cannot see how PHP handles this.

Does PHP have the equivalent to Java, and is it operating system specific? I am using Windows.  What would best practices be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, your best bet is to use a "[lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29)", in this case a file lock.

See https://www.php.net/flock for more information on file locking.

Answer (score 5):

PHP doesn't do threads.  Don't worry about it*.

I'm positive there are reasons that you might be worried about deadlocks and raceconditions, but only if you're handling a large application across many front-ends communicating with the same back-end.

But, like, yeah, don't worry about it.

Comment: The PHP documentation disagrees with you.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: @LukeA.Leber you do realize the answer is over 5 years old, and answered 2 years PRIOR to pthreads being added as PECL extension? Release 0.0.33 (alpha) was 9/25/2012 and the extension isn't marked stable until March 2014?

Comment: Nope, didn't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

In a single threaded application this is no a problem. For the database situation however, I would go with transactions. Transactions will basically do what you would expect fron the synchronized - do several operations in one atomic operation, either all succeed or all failed.l

Comment: Thanks for the advise Dmitri I will investigate Transactions!

Answer (score 1):

The PHP-file is not run in parallel so within one instance not using the function [pcntl-fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) a race-condition cannot occur. When you are looking at the side of MySQL, it is fully parallel.

Comment: could there be an issue from MySQL? or am I missing the point?

Comment: MySQL is fully async, so no problem. The PHP-script is run from top to bottom so just think of it as a food-recipe or something. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the sem_acquire is the best way to do it. "blocks (if necessary) until the semaphore can be acquired. A process attempting to acquire a semaphore which it has already acquired will block forever if acquiring the semaphore would cause its maximum number of semaphore to be exceeded. " https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a multithreaded application you can use the `pthreads` extension and your objects that are intended for multi-threaded use should extend the `Threaded` class which has a `synchronized` method.

The `pthreads` extension is not operating system specific but requires the `ZTS` (Zend Thread Safety) build of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

yes, with Process Control Extensions
http://php.net/manual/ru/threaded.synchronized.php