# How to detect a critical region in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, critical-section

I wanted to ask how do I detect a critical region in Java? I understand that it's to implement mutual exclusion with two atomic processes but what are the general things I just look for to determine that this is a critical region.

I'm very curious to know whether:

- all synchronized methods in Java critical regions?
- are critical regions only found in concurrent systems in Java?

Comment: "Are critical regions only found in concurrent systems in Java?" - How would you **define** "a critical region"? If a system is not "concurrent" - how can the system meet that definition?

Comment: A critical section is what you define it to be. You can have critical sections which are critical from a performance rather than a thread safety point of view.

Comment: You don't detect them. You *design* them. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I believe you think that critical region are part of the code where synchronisation take places, or maybe werethere is a common resource for multiple thread. Is that what you mean ? Before the edit, there was written you read this from multiple source, what are these sources ? And of course it's not clear, that's why he is asking this question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey in this question he should be referring 'critical section' under the context of concurrency. :))

Answer (score 3):

In concurrency a **[Critical Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)** is simply a code fragment where ***one thread can write/read into/from memory when some other is writing into the same memory*** or ***one thread is going to write into the memory when some other thread is reading from the same memory***.

Summary

- Thread1 - write  |  Thread2 - write  |  Safeness - **No**
- Thread1 - write  |  Thread2 - read   |  Safeness - **No**
- Thread1 - read   |  Thread2 - write  |  Safeness - **No**
- Thread1 - read   |  Thread2 - read   |  Safeness - **Yes**

i.e. They are the section in our program where it can cause possible errors/malfunctions if we don't implement proper [control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) over it. (Ex: locks, semaphores, barriers etc.)

And it is not only applied for Java. It applies to any programming language which supports threads.

Comment: +1, I didn't knew this was an official term in concurent programming: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section (even if it's section rather than region as OP said). As for the second question, I'm not sure the question was about Java especially, but more like : "are critical regions only found in concurrent systems ?", but the answer would obviously be yes, as this term only concern parrallel programming.

Comment: @Asoub yes. The word 'critical' can have different interpretations as per the context it is used. I just stated what it means in the context of concurrent programming. :)) And thnx for your source, I added that to my answer. :))

Answer (score 2):

> all synchronized methods in Java critical regions?

Not only `synchronized` methods/blocks, code using [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)API too safeguard critical region ( section)

Multiple ways of guarding critical section.

**1. synchronized methods:**

```
public synchronized void incrementCounter(){
    ++counter;
}
```

**2. synchronized statements**

```
public int getCounter(){
    synchronized(this){
        return counter;
    }
}
```

**3. Lock API**

```
class X {
   private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   // ...

   public void m() {
     lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
     try {
       // ... method body, which is critical section
     } finally {
       lock.unlock()
     }
   }
 }
```

Useful SE questions:

[Why use a ReentrantLock if one can use synchronized(this)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821801/why-use-a-reentrantlock-if-one-can-use-synchronizedthis/36827191#36827191)

[Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java/36692190#36692190)

> are critical regions only found in concurrent systems in Java?

No. They can be found in other languages too.

Related SE question:

[C# version of java's synchronized keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-sharp-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword)

[Does PHP have the equivilant to Java 'synchronized' , or is this not required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809001/does-php-have-the-equivilant-to-java-synchronized-or-is-this-not-required)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if some value is shared between multiple threads, if  yes can it be deemed "corrupt" when the value is set or get but these threads, If a use case breaks due to this corrupt value lock it down its a critical region.